# how to set key with more value(comma separated) in url angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my url is

```
http://localhost:8000/#/?key=value
```

**how to make multiple valued key in url in angular js??** like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#/?key=value,value2,value3
```

and **how to remove particular key for example value2 from url?**

I have read about `$location.search` but I can't find this scenario.

can anybody help me for this.

I had tried `$location.search(key,value);`

but it replace the key's value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var values_string = $location.search('key');
var values_array = values_string.split(',');

indexOfValue2 = values_array.indexOf('value2');
values_array = values_array.splice(indexOfValue2, 1);
```

Comment: thank you for replying now one more thing is that if my url is like this http://localhost:8080/#/?key=value,value2,value3 and now i want to add value4 in same key then how i can do that ???

Comment: Use `values_array.push('value4');`